# Choosing between DynamoDB Streams vs. Kinesis Streams for IoT Sensor data

Tags: aws-lambda, streaming, iot, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a fleet of 250 Wifi-enabled IoT sensors streaming weight data. Each devices samples once per second. I am requesting help between choosing AWS DynamoDB Streams vs. AWS Kinesis Streams to to store and process this data in real-time. Here are some additional requirements:

- I need to keep all raw data in a SQL-accessible table.
- I also need to clean the raw stream data with Python's Pandas library to recognize device-level events based on weight changes (e.g. if weight of sensor #1 increases, record as "sensor #1 increased by x lbs @ XX:XX PM" If no change, do nothing).
- I need that change-event data (interpreted with library from the raw data streams) to be accessible in real time dashboard (e.g. device #1 weight just went to zero, prompting employee to refill container #1)

Either DDB Streams or Kinesis Streams can support Lambda functions, which is what I'll use for the data cleaning, but I've read the documentation and comparison articles and can't distinguish which is best for my use case. Cost is not a key consideration. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you will need a few pieces of infrastructure for a full solution.

1. I think you could use Kinesis and firehose to write to a database to store the raw data in a way that can be queried with SQL.
2. For the data cleaning step, I think you will need to use a stateful stream processor like [flink](https://flink.apache.org/) or [bytewax](https://www.bytewax.io/) and then the transformed data can be written to a real-time database or back to kinesis so that it can be consumed in a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

[DynamoDB stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) works with [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html). It streams row changes to be picked up by downstream services like [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html). You mentioned that you want data to be stored in SQL data base. DynamoDB is a NOSQL databse. So you can exclude that service.

Not sure why you want to have data in SQL database. If it is timeseries data, you would probably store them into a time series db like [TimeStream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/what-is-timestream.html).

If you are using [AWS IoT Core](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/index.html) to send data over MQTT to AWS, you can [forward those messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/kinesis-rule-action.html) to [Kinesis Data Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/introduction.html) (or SQS). Then you can have a [lambda triggered on messages received in Kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html). This lambda can process the data and store them in the DB you want.

Answer (score 0):

##### High level differences on why to choose one over the other

| Properties | Kinesis Data Streams for DynamoDB | DynamoDB Streams |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data retention | Up to 1 year. | 24 hours. |
| Kinesis Client Library (KCL) support | Supports KCL versions 1.X and 2.X. | Supports KCL version 1.X. |
| Number of consumers | Up to 5 simultaneous consumers per shard, or up to 20 simultaneous consumers per shard with enhanced fan-out. | Up to 2 simultaneous consumers per shard. |
| Throughput quotas | Unlimited. | Subject to throughput quotas by DynamoDB table and AWS Region. |
| Record delivery model | Pull model over HTTP using GetRecords and with enhanced fan-out, Kinesis Data Streams pushes the records over HTTP/2 by using SubscribeToShard. | Pull model over HTTP using GetRecords. |
| Ordering of records | The timestamp attribute on each stream record can be used to identify the actual order in which changes occurred in the DynamoDB table. | For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the item. |
| Duplicate records | Duplicate records might occasionally appear in the stream. | No duplicate records appear in the stream. |
| Stream processing options | Process stream records using AWS Lambda, Kinesis Data Analytics, Kinesis data firehose , or AWS Glue streaming ETL. | Process stream records using AWS Lambda or DynamoDB Streams Kinesis adapter. |
| Durability level | Availability zones to provide automatic failover without interruption. | Availability zones to provide automatic failover without interruption. |